# python twisted error "import pkg_resources"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, twisted

i am try to learn python twisted.i face some error where i run any twisted program, i am can't understand what is problem in my system or in python twisted

and there is error::

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/__init__.py:3: 
UserWarning:Module twisted was already imported from    
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/__init__.pyc, but 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahn-0.10.5_2-py2.7.egg 
is being added to sys.path
import pkg_resources
```

and there is screen shot:

[image: terminal screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an error, just a warning (hence `UserWarning`) and has to do with the way that you've installed Autobahn.  It appears to me that you installed it with `sudo pip install`, which you should pretty much never do; instead `sudo apt-get install` or `pip install` things into a `virtualenv`.

In any case, it's harmless and you can ignore it.

Comment: hey Glyph Lefkowitz, thanks for answer. i was this fix error.